# Read HTML content of webview widgets

Tags: android, webview, widget

I want to read HTML content of webview widgets.

Is there any property or method which can be used to fetch the HTML of the currently open page?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can inject a javascript into webView and get the html element. Check below code...

```
class MyJavaScriptInterface {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showHTML(final String html) {
        //HTML content of the page 
    }
}
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.showHTML('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
```

Comment: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: window.HTMLOUT.showHTML is not a function", source:  (1)